# How do I get url params with a question mark in react js?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm making a react app and I stumbled upon a problem that I couldn't figure out.
I have a url `http://localhost/panel/?code=123456789`. How do I get `CODE`?

I've tried this:

```js
export default function App() {
    return (
      
      
      <div className="App">
        <Router>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/:code" component={Panel}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
        <h1>hi</h1>

        </div>
        
    
      );
}

function Panel(){
    const {code} = useParams();
        return (
        <div>
            <h3>ID: {code}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but that gives me `ID: panel`. So I tried

```js
          <Route exact path="/panel/:code" component={Panel}/>
```

but then their is now no h3 or `ID:` on the page just the `<h1>hi</h1>`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? And how can I get `CODE`?

Comment: Documentation reference for this "https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters".
Custome hook with one line code is the best and I always suggest to use it. Thus, it becomes truly reusable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
let search = window.location.search
search.split("=")[1]
```

It will give you the code in your url

Comment: In the panel function?

Comment: This is how you get the code from url, you can use it wherever you want

Answer (score 2):

Try this code below in your **panel** component

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let code = urlParams.get('code');
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are already using react-router-dom, I strongly recommend using useLocation() to always get the correct and apt value.

Documentation reference for this:
[https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters"](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters%22).

A custom hook in documentation example with one line code is the best and I always suggest to use it. Thus, it becomes truly reusable and easy to maintain.

For reference:

```
// A custom hook that builds on useLocation to parse
// the query string for you.
export function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
```

Use this custom hook in any component across the application as below:

```
import {useQuery} from './useQuery';
export function QueryParamsDemo() {
  let query = useQuery();
  return(
    <p>query param name = {query.get("name")}</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: worked as expected, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-router-dom`.

```
import {
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";

....
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location?.search.split("=")[1].split(".")[0]);
```